# Xcode error Build input files cannot be found with Lottie-ios

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, lottie

So after a broken merge in my react-native project, basically a merge of logos, this error came out from nowhere. It was working perfectly yesterday.
The only thing I did, it was to install react-native-bootsplash and uninstall right after, but I think it didn't change anything

> Build input files cannot be found:
> '/Users/benohit/dev/happySunnyHour/happysunnyhourfront/node_modules/lottie-ios/Sources/Public/Animation/AnimationViewInitializers.swift',
> '/Users/benohit/dev/happySunnyHour/happysunnyhourfront/node_modules/lottie-ios/Sources/Public/Animation/AnimationPublic.swift',
> '/Users/benohit/dev/happySunnyHour/happysunnyhourfront/node_modules/lottie-ios/Sources/Public/Primitives/Color.swift',
> '/Users/benohit/dev/happySunnyHour/happysunnyhourfront/node_modules/lottie-ios/Sources/Public/iOS/AnimationViewBase.swift',
> '/Users/benohit/dev/happySunnyHour/happysunnyhourfront/node_modules/lottie-ios/Sources/Private/Model/Animation.swift',
> '/Users/benohit/dev/happySunnyHour/happysunnyhourfront/node_modules/lottie-ios/Sources/Public/Animation/AnimationView.swift',
> '/Users/benohit/dev/happySunnyHour/happysunnyhourfront/node_modules/lottie-ios/Sources/Private/MainThread/NodeRenderSystem/NodeProperties/ValueProviders/KeyframeInterpolator.swift'.
> Did you forget to declare these files as outputs of any script phases
> or custom build rules which produce them?

When I check in the modules files [image: lottie files]
The name added 'Lottie' before and also in the file. like :

```
extension LottieAnimationView{ ...
```

Why this error appeared? And especially where does it come from ?
Is there a solution?